# Is it possible to build a single executable Perl program that will run on a variety of platforms?

Tags: perl, executable, par

I have a Perl script that I've written and can compile it using pp (PAR). I'm curious if it's possible to make a single executable that is completely portable (run on linux & windows) or do I have to create 2 executables (one for linux and one for windows). I'm not interested in options using perlapp or perl2exe, I'm strictly looking for a PAR/pp option here. Also I'm not looking for PAR's capability to create a .par file and have a stub Perl environment pre-deployed for the OS varieties.

EDIT:

When running the file command against a binary built on my linux system it shows the binary is of the following type:

```
% file my_app
my_app: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped.
```

This would seem to indicate that it will only run on a linux system.

Comment: linux and windows executables have different formats

Comment: @yi_H yes, but are those formats incompatible with one another?

Comment: Yes the formats are incompatible with one another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's impossible to build a single executable that will run on a variety of platforms as they use different formats for their binaries.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda figured this was the case but thought I'd ask to get a definitive answer. I'm assuming that because PAR/pp builds a platform specific binary they're incompatible across different OS/platform combinations.

Comment: I don't *think* it is **completely** impossible, but it would be **very** difficult. The ELF header would take the place of the DOS stub in the PE format. Location 0x3c would have to be specific to the PE format. From there it would be a somewhat simple matter to interlace ELF blocks and PE blocks. I doubt that any of the blocks could do double duty. Which means that the executable would end up being twice the size.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, How would linux find the ELF header? Does it understand PE? (I'm not disputing what you said, just trying to figure out how it would work.)

Comment: ELF headers are at the start of the file. PE files have a DOS stub at the start. When Windows looks at a PE file, it ignores the stub. Windows instead looks for an address at location 0x3C, which points to the PE header. Which means the PE header could be anywhere in the file. Basically as long as the ELF header doesn't interfere with 0x3C, it may be possible. I would say that it is far from practicable though. You may have to go through a lot of work so that the blocks are ignored by the other format.